# How can I get full data_type using DESCRIBE TABLE in Spark/Hive SQL?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hiveql, database-schema, sqldatatypes

We can use `DESCRIBE TABLE table_name` to get the schema of a table in Spark/Hive SQL. However, the data_type column might not return the full type if a data_type is too long. See below for such an example. Is there a way to get the full data types of columns using Spark/Hive SQL?

struct<sameid:string,sawt:int,sawe:double,sawbid:string,sawsid:string,sawfae:double,sawcid:string,sawadid:string,sawdid:int,sawfe:double,sawid:string,sawaid:int,sapbmuc:string,saanxuc:string,saeapt:int,salv:int,saanxt:int,sat:int,sapbmpubid:int,saanxmid:int,sapbmsid:int,saebaypid:int,sapbmt:int,saanxpid:string,... 7 more fields>

Comment: df.printSchema()?

Answer (score 0):

you can  use : DataFrame.printSchema()